# array_key_exists is not working well

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I have this array:

```
$variableNames = [
        'x1',
        'x2',
        'x3',
        'x4',
        'x5',
        'x6',
        'x7'
    ];
```

But, when i use array_key_exists function like this:

```
array_key_exists('x3', $this->variableNames)
```

It return `false`. But, if i have this array:

```
$variableNames = [
        'x1' => null,
        'x2' => null,
        'x3' => null,
        'x4' => null,
        'x5' => null,
        'x6' => null,
        'x7' => null
    ];
```

It return `true`. How can i use the first array, and get `true`?
In the first array, the value is null also, like the second array. So, why the first array return `false` and the second array return `true`?

Comment: in above array use in_array() cause key is 0,1,2... not 'x1'.....

Comment: I believe that the code thinks in your first case that the "keys" is values and makes the keys 0,1,2 etc. Try to var_dump the frist case

Comment: you are confusing key with values,in your array the keys are implcit 0=>x1 and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) search for keys not values.

In your first case, you `x3` is in value.

So, its not searching.

In this case you can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), this function searches 
for values.

In second case, `x3` is key, therefore, searching properly.

Answer (score 2):

The keys are not null, never.

```
$variableNames = [
        'x1',
        'x2',
        'x3',
        'x4',
        'x5',
        'x6',
        'x7'
    ];
```

means

```
$variableNames = [
        0 => 'x1',
        1 => 'x2',
        2 => 'x3',
        3 => 'x4',
        4 => 'x5',
        5 => 'x6',
        6 => 'x7'
    ];
```

use

```
in_array('x3', $this->variableNames)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array()` instead of `array_key_exists()`

In your case,

```
$variableNames = ['x1',
        'x2',
        'x3',
        'x4',
        'x5',
        'x6',
        'x7'];

if (in_array("x3", $this->variableNames)) {
    echo "Found x3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No your incorrect. The function works well, you're just using it incorrectly. `array_key_exists` looks for the key, not value.

The first array you provided, is actually treated as a array of value. They have index keys, which are automatically added by PHP. I you `print_r($variableNames)`, you'll see it will return the following.

```
$variableNames = [
        0 => 'x1',
        1 => 'x2',
        2 => 'x3',
        3 => 'x4',
        4 => 'x5',
        5 => 'x6',
        6 => 'x7'
    ];
```

You would need to search for the value instead. Use `in_array()` or `isset()`, both ways are right, one is just more convenient than the other.